# How do I transfer the ownership of a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am no longer working with the person who originally created my Chrome extension, and I need to manage and push updates to the extension for our current users.

Is there any way of transferring ownership? He is happy to do it, but has not been able to find a way.

Comment: [A cautionary tale](http://www.labnol.org/internet/sold-chrome-extension/28377/) for anybody landing here and considering transferring ownership to an unknown party

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a Google tech support question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 41):

You have to fill in some forms with Google.

You can find the Chrome Web Store account transfer request form here: http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/request.py?contact_type=dev_account_transfer

Comment: current URL: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/dev_account_transfer

Comment: hi is it affect existing customer or payments we're receiving?

Answer (score 7):

You may [create a Google Group and use it](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing_1) as your publisher.
Remember that:

> You can only set up group publishing once and create one group publisher account.

If you want to transfer extension **to group**, then:

1. Select *"All Publishers"* in the dashboard.
2. Under target group click *"Transfer your existing item(s) to this publisher"*.

[image]

In practice I was able to share publishing access among group **owners**, not group participants, but you may experiment yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that we're talking about an extension hosted on Google's extension gallery, there's no mechanism for transferring ownership available in the developer dashboard. Transfers of ownership have to be done manually by someone internally.  The extension's owner will need to send an email to [the "chromium-extensions" group](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/topics) explaining the situation, and someone from the extensions team will get back with you relatively soon to get the details.

Until there's a better mechanism for this (multiple owners, for instance), I'd suggest that you create a new Google account to share between the extension's owners, and ask for that address to be assigned ownership.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer, i have sent a mail to the group.

Comment: hi is it affect existing customer or payments we're receiving?

Comment: Is this still the case? Can we now transfer ownership?

Answer (score 1):

You can now transfer your extension by submitting this form:

https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/one_stop_support

> Transfers can take up to 7 days